# Recently, when using vue3, don't you use 'vue-property-decorator' a lot?

Tags: vue.js, vue-property-decorator

A lot of the features of 'vue-property-decorator' seem to have been transferred to '@Options'.

People who use the latest vue3 are not using vue-property-decorator?